# British Airside Visa - what happens if connecting flight is cancelled or rescheduled?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I'm from Sri Lanka traveling to the Bahamas with a connecting flight at Heathrow. If I have a British airside visa and the connecting flight is cancelled or rescheduled for 2-3 days later, what will happen?

Answer (score 7):

If the connection or one leg is cancelled, the entire itinerary is cancelled or rebooked. They will NOT fly you to Heathrow, if your connection is 3 days later.

The only exception would be if the cancellation is out of the blue, i.e. not know when you board your flight in Sri Lanka. This is exceedingly rare and most airport/countries of emergency procedures for that. Typically you would get a short term emergency visa or they put you up in an accomodation with no access to the country.

Comment: This answer is correct if the traveler is on a single itinerary. Nothing in the question discloses, however, if the "connecting flight" is on the same itinerary as the first flight, or is on a second and separate itinerary. If the OP made two separate bookings with two different airlines, then cancellation of one flight will have no effect on the other, and neither airline will be responsible for the missed connection.